# External page load issue in Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps

I'm directly showing some external web page in my Windows 8 app, and this external page loads too much delayed at times and some times it does not load all. Someone please help me to overcome this problem. I'm using XAML/C# for the app.

following is my code to load the external page, how can I check weather the page is loaded properly in the app?

```
this.InitializeComponent();
textboxUri.Text = "http://www.google.com/";
WebView1.Navigate(new Uri(textboxUri.Text));
```

Comment: Please give the code snippet of your trial by that people will be able to help you better

Comment: @RinoTom code snippet added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Webview class has a [LoadCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.loadcompleted.aspx) event, I would imagine you want something like this (pseudo code):

```
{
    textboxUri.Text = "http://www.google.com/";
    WebView1.Navigate(new Uri(textboxUri.Text));

    WebView1.LoadCompleted += LoadCompletedEvent;
}

void LoadCompletedEvent(object sender, eventargs e)
{
    //Now the website has loaded, do what you want here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look here to the MSDN sample code:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7/sourcecode?fileId=57963&pathId=298223712

Hope this will help you :)